# How do we extract named entities in scala using any nlp library

Tags: scala, nlp, databricks, named-entity-recognition, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I have a huge text file and I have to extract only named entites in from this file. I am using Scala language and Databricks cluster for this.

```
val input = sc.textFile('....Mypath...').flatMap(line => line.split("""\W+"""))

val namedEnt = something(input)
```

Can anyone tell what to code to get named entities?

Comment: check out step6 from this document: https://towardsdatascience.com/natural-language-processing-in-apache-spark-using-nltk-part-1-2-58c68824f660 and https://dzone.com/articles/using-opennlp-for-named-entity-recognition-in-scal

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your `input` to a DataFrame (ex: `.toDF`), this is how you can get the Named Entities out:

Just an example of Spark NLP installation

```sh
spark-shell --packages JohnSnowLabs:spark-nlp:2.4.0
```

Actual example:

```scala
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.pretrained.PretrainedPipeline
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.SparkNLP

SparkNLP.version() 
// make sure you are using the latest release 2.4.x

// Download and load the pre-trained pipeline that has NER in English
// Full list: https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp-models
val pipeline = PretrainedPipeline("recognize_entities_dl", lang="en")

//Transfrom your DataFrame to a new DataFrame that has NER column
val annotation = pipeline.transform(inputDF)

// This would look something like this:
/*
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| id|                text|            document|            sentence|               token|          embeddings|                 ner|       entities|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1|Google has announ...|[[document, 0, 10...|[[document, 0, 10...|[[token, 0, 5, Go...|[[word_embeddings...|[[named_entity, 0...|[[chunk, 0, 5, Go...|
|  2|Donald John Trump...|[[document, 0, 92...|[[document, 0, 92...|[[token, 0, 5, Do...|[[word_embeddings...|[[named_entity, 0...|[[chunk, 0, 16, D...|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
*/

// This is where the results for entities are:

annotation.select("entities.result").show
```

Let me know if you have any questions or problems with your input data and I'll update my answer.

**References**:

- https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp
- https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp-models
- https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp-workshop